# Replace wrong encodings in a data-frame

Tags: r, string, replace, encoding, gsub

How can I replace all occurences of a certain strings (e.g. "ÃƒÅ“) by it's corresponding special-character? (unfortunately the character-encodings are wrong).

For example I'd like to replace "ÃƒÂ¼" by "ü", "ÃƒÂ¤" by "ä" etc. I can do this with the following code, but how can I apply this to every column in the data.frame? And how can I do this most efficiently?

```
df$colum<-gsub("ÃƒÂ¼", "ü", daf$column)
```

Thank you!

Comment: just as comment, is it possible to read it in different encode? that would be easier

Comment: see also `rvest::repair_encoding`, it helped me on several occasions but doesn't work on these particular examples (though it might be because it's been copied and pasted here so test it anyway).

Answer (score 1):

There might be several ways to go about this depending on what the actual problem is:

**A**:

If your original data (e.g. csv-file etc) looks fine and you only see the bad encoding in R, you should try to read the file with the correct encoding - most reader and writer functions take a parameter for this and UTF-8 should work in most cases. You could, for example try `read.csv(your_file_path, fileEncoding='UTF-8')` or similar (depending on how you read your data.)

**B**:

The data is actually broken (i.e. someone has messed up the encoding previously and it's not your fault for reading it wrong) and you now want to fix it manually (for just a couple of characters, e.g. ä, ö, ü, ß.)

Then, using the `dplyr` package you could:

1. make a function that fixes the errors:

   `my_fun <- function(str){
        str <- gsub("ÃƒÂ¼", "ü", str)
        str <- gsub("ÃƒÂ¤", "ä", str)
        < additional steps >
        str
      }`
2. Apply it to every character-column of your data frame:

`df %>% mutate_if(is.character, my_function)`

Comment: That's correct. Factors store an integer for each value and the corresponding string in the `levels` attribute. For factors you would only need to change the `levels`, not apply the function to each value. If you quickly need factors in and factors out and don't care about speed, you could do: `mutate_if(is.factor, ~as.factor(my_function(as.character(.x)))`